# How can I validate an access token from PHP when it was generated from a mobile app?

Tags: php, android, facebook, authentication

I'm writing an Android app that I would like to authenticate with Facebook, and then contact my own web server after a session has been established with Facebook. My web server communicates with the Android app via JSON only, so I can't redirect the web page to get the user the log in.

I can send the access token and user ID from Facebook to the web server, but I need a way of validating the input.

I've looked at some other threads (namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400356/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-to-facebook) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220572/checking-if-a-user-is-logged-in-to-facebook)), and it looks like there are multiple ways to communicate a user's login status to a remote web server.

Which method here is standard? Are there any trade-offs I should be aware of?

1. `$Facebook->getUser()` will give me the ID of the user that is currently requesting the page (does this work if the web page isn't authenticated, but the mobile app is?)
2. `$Facebook->getAccessToken()` will give me the session key of the logged in user (same question as in 1)
3. `$Facebook->api('/me')` will not return null as long as someone is logged in

Comment: I don't understand the significance of this statement: *"My web server communicates with the Android app via JSON only, so I can't embed iframes in my web server code"*. Regardless, why can't your app just `POST` the access token to your server, along with the user ID?

Comment: @Madbreaks, assuming I do that, how is that secure? Shouldn't the server verify with Facebook that the access token/user ID is valid?

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your question. It sounds to me like you want to authenticate the user with Facebook via your app (and not directly App <---> Facebook), is that correct?

Comment: The user logs into my app on an Android device. My app's web server hosts some content that's not available on Facebook, so the Android app must also be able to contact the web server. I need a way for the Android app to notify the web server that the user has a valid Facebook session.

Comment: How is your user authenticating with Facebook though?

Comment: Through the Facebook SDK on Android

Comment: Right but *which* SDK? My question is: is your app authenticating directly with Facebook, or is the authentication happening App ---> Your Server --> Facebook?

Comment: Ah, I understand your question. My Android app authenticates directly to Facebook. I want the web server to validate the user id/access token that Facebook returned to the Android app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just send the access token over a HTTPS connection to your server, and you can validate it with a call to `/me` and `/app` to verify that the app and user ID both match what you expect

See also the Access Token debug endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/

Comment: So the server doesn't have to be logged in as anyone to authenticate /me and /app?

Comment: The access token is what you use to 'log in' to the API - the login flows in the docs are how a logged-in (Facebook) user gives your app an access token to take actions on their behalf